# How to implement invitations limits per user when using the Invite Module?

Tags: 7

So, basically, I'm trying to create a private invitation-only forum. I'm using the [invite module](https://www.drupal.org/project/invite).

Is possible to set invitation-restrictions? For example, each user can only invite a total of 3 users, or a user can only send one invite per month?

Also, do unclaimed sent invites expire?

Comment: The answer is yes, the [invite module keeps does track expirations](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/invite.install?id=7.x-4.0-beta2#n48). In the future, please limit your questions to one per post.

Answer (score 1):

## Invitation expiration

Quote from the [Community documentation about the Invite module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2205953) (from its installation instructions):

> ***Invitation expiry***: Set the expiry period for user invitations, in days (default select up to 365 days).

So the answer to your 2nd question ***do unclaimed sent invites expire?*** is YES. That's what's stated also in comment #3 of the issue about [Set expiry date to never](https://www.drupal.org/node/653724).

## Setting invitation restrictions

Looks like this feature "used to be available in a prior version of the module". And according to comment #3 of the issue about [Limit invitation per user/role](https://www.drupal.org/node/2048801), it should be back some day.

While waiting for that to happen, you may want to use some type of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) integration. Such as the solution as included in the issue about [Rules integration for D7](https://www.drupal.org/node/1539336). It includes a patch for the 7.x-2.x version (status "RTBC"). If you're using 7.x-4.x however, then note the issue status "Needs work" ...

Answer (score 0):

While the invite module doesn't provide this functionality, per se, it does provide a series of [API hooks](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/invite.api.php?id=7.x-4.0-beta2) that will allow you to extend functionality. In your use case, you need to keep track of your user quota as invites are sent/accepted with [`hook_invite_send()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/invite.api.php?id=7.x-4.0-beta2#n85) / [`hook_invite_accept()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/invite.api.php?id=7.x-4.0-beta2#n30).

You'll also need to [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) the [`invite_form()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/includes/invite.admin.inc?id=7.x-4.0-beta2#n156) so that it has a validation function that rejects users who go over their quota.